# the infinitesimal generator of $(B_t,l(0,t))$

Tags: probability

Let $(B_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a one-dimensional, standard Brownian motion and let $(l(0,t))_{t\geq0}$ be its local time at the origin. The process $((B_t,l(0,t)))_{t\geq0}$ is a markov process on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_+$. Which is its infinitesimal generator?

Comment: I could advise you the book Change of Time and Change of Measure, it's quite recent of 2010. There may be an answer.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, I'll take a look.

Comment: Not every Markov process has an infinitesimal generator, only (Itô) diffusions have. What makes you think (B,L) is a diffusion?